# Is it possible to retrieve data from parse.com using objective-c and show it in website?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, parse-platform

I have an iOS app in which I use parse.com as backend service. Now, I hired someone to do a website interface using HTML and CSS. I want to share the same data between iOS app and website, I know parse.com offers me a few ways to do this, including creating a `javaScript`application. The problem is, my programmer doesn't have any experience in `JavaScript`, nor do I.

My question is: Is it possible to use what I have (objective-c, xcode) as far as retrieving data from parse.com and showing on website? Even if I need to code something new, is it possible to use objective-c together with HTML and CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse has several APIs, one of which is REST. Your web developer should use the REST API to get data from Parse

https://www.parse.com/docs/rest

Answer (score 1):

If there is will there is way, but you'll be making something really specific to your use and will be non standard and will be immediately hard to maintain, I recommend that you hire another developer and do things properly using the technologies given to you by parse !. if the cost will be high now I can promise you it'll be much higher if you went the path you're going to now.

So my answer is:

**Yes**, everything is possible and **no**, don't do it ! :)

**Edit:** Added an example to a possible way to do it to actually answer OP's question.

**Example case:**

1-Create a simple Mac Application in Xcode that fetches data exactly like you do it on iOS, and store the needed data into a database of your choice on your server

2-You now have access to the data you needed from parse, but on a local mirror. you will need some tool to fetch that data though, I recommend a simple PHP script.

Note that this will require an OSX server to always be running to fetch that data, you'll also need of find a way to fetch data on demand when a user needs it Vs. polling at specified intervals, this will hardly scale and will be costly as I said.

Comment: Thanks, great example. Can you give me an example on how that would differ if I use `JavaScript`?

Comment: The data will need to be available when user needs it, of course. That said, isn't it possible to call the mac application directly from website (CSS, HTML) and get the results from parse?

Comment: This is not the way. Use the REST API, which is meant for this